# Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar (default-cli) on project

Tags: sonarqube, azure-pipelines

Facing issue while running sonar in VSTS under code analysis section.Please help me out on this.

> 2018-06-11T07:50:44.8401948Z [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar
>   (default-cli) on project testproj: Fail to request
>   https://sonarqube.tac.com/api/ce/submit?projectKey=com.tac.idd.dps:sealer&projectName=sealer:
>   timeout: Connection reset by peer: socket write error

Comment: This error is usually caused by a proxy between the scanner running on the build agent and the SonarQube server.

Comment: @JulienH.-SonarSourceTeam, How to fix this issue now? Its failing in all the jobs in VSTS. Please help me out.

Comment: Could anyone help me on this issue ?

Comment: Can you access that sonarqube server from build agent server directly?

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT,Yes I can able to access SonarQube server but its failing wit the error above mentioned.

Comment: From build agent machine? How do you configure proxy?

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT, Earlier all our Sonar builds were ran successfully but now its failing with the above error.We are connecting to that Sonar machine from many instances of VSTS but from one instance we are facing the above issue.Not sure how to handle this issue.

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT,Please see the complete log. BUILD FAILURE
2018-06-13T06:51:23.9360930Z [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2018-06-13T06:51:23.9361648Z [INFO] Total time: 03:12 min
2018-06-13T06:51:23.9361945Z [INFO] Finished at: 2018-06-13T06:51:23+00:00
2018-06-13T06:51:24.2064805Z [INFO] Final Memory: 46M/499M
2018-06-13T06:51:24.2065448Z [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2018-06-13T06:51:24.2065850Z [ERROR] Failed to execute goal

Comment: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project DCommon: There are test failures.
2018-06-13T06:51:24.2066165Z [ERROR] 
2018-06-13T06:51:24.2066439Z [ERROR] Please refer to D:\a\1\s\DCommon\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
2018-06-13T06:51:24.2066767Z [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
2018-06-13T06:51:24.2066969Z [ERROR] 
2018-06-13T06:51:24.2067402Z [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.

Comment: 2018-06-13T06:51:24.8670379Z Timestamp is not available for one or more testsuites. Total run duration is being calculated as the sum of time durations of detected testsuites
2018-06-13T06:51:24.8673096Z Only single test suite found, parsing its information

Comment: Do you use Hosted agent?

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT,Yes I am using hosted agent only.

Comment: With Hosted agent, the sourceqube server should be accessible from internet, but seems that I can't access it. You said that other VSTS instance works fine, are the builds uses the Hosted agent too?

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT,Yes , I can connect from other VSTS instances using hosted agent and everything went well.But for one instance its throwing error.Earlier It was working fine without any issues.Since 2 days its failing with the above issue from one instance of VSTS

Comment: Do you compare these build definitions' json files?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below command to archive your issue. I was facing the same but below command worked.

`- mvn verify sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:Port -Dsonar.login=Token -Dsonar.login=Sonar_username -Dsonar.password=Sonar_password`

Cheers..!!!